# specify condition before loading vuejs component

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vuejs, I want to have a check done before the component is loaded, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

what I want to do is if `"this.$store.getters.user.id"` and `"this.$route.params.id"` are not equal before the component is loaded
`"this.$router.push({name: 'home', params: {id" : this.$store.getters.user.id}})"`

```
{
        path: '/:id',
        name: 'home',
        component: () => import('../Views/Admin/Home.vue'),
        meta: {
            guard: 'auth'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'admin',
                component: () => import('../Views/Admin/HomeProfile.vue'),
                name: 'admin',
                meta: {
                    guard: 'auth'
                },
            }
        ]
    },
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if (store.getters.user) {
        if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.guard === 'guest')) next({name: 'home'})
        else next();

    } else {
        if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.guard === 'auth')) next({name: 'login'})
        else next();
    }
})
```

Comment: how do i do that? router in this way

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662676/10975709 it's kind of related. in your case, just check the store instead of `checkAuth` function and use `meta` instead of route's name.

Comment: no it didn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this function before every route in your application, you could use router's `beforeEach` function to check that.

`router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { }`.

If this is only for one or some routes, you could set the property beforeEnter to the route.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

---

In your beforeEach function, you need to make the validation you said you want.

```
if(this.$store.getters.user.id !== to.params.id) 
   next({
          name: 'home', 
          params: { id: this.$store.getters.user.id }
   });
```

Comment: how do i do this? I edited the topic, and I don't know much

Comment: I have edited the answer to try to add an example for you.